# Defining a conditional ability on a model with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

First, my associations:

```
Form has_many :agreements
Agreement belongs_to :student
```

I'm trying to define an Ability where the current user `can :read, Form` when one of its agreements belongs to the the current user.

I've attempted to define the ability like so:

```
Ability.rb:

can :read, Form do |f|
  f.agreements.select { |a| a.student_id == user.id }.nil? == false
end
```

I've also tried:

```
can :read, Form, agreements: { student_id:  user.id }
```

Unfortunately, the first solution allows all students to view all Forms, even if they are not attached to one of the form agreements. The second solution doesn't allow any student to view a Form, even if they are attached to one of the form's agreements.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is no good:

```
f.agreements.select { |a| a.student_id == user.id }.nil? == false
```

The reason is that `#select` will always return an array. If there are no agreements where the `student_id` matches the `user.id`, then you'll get an empty array (`[]`). But `#nil?` on any array, including an empty array, is always false. So this line always evaluates to true.

The fix is quite simple. Use the rails method `#blank?` instead of `#nil?`. That will return true if the object is `nil` OR if it's `empty`. And `[].empty?` returns `true`.

**tldr:** Change the above line to

```
f.agreements.select { |a| a.student_id == user.id }.blank? == false
```

Comment: There's actually another potential problem with the line, but it affects performance rather than behavior. That is, you really ought to be doing this query in sql (assuming you're using a sql backend of some kind) rather than in ruby. i.e., `f.agreements.where(:student_id => user.id).blank?`

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thanks for helpful info.

A question however:
All of my models inherit from ActiveRecord. Why does running an sql query like `where` have better performance that ruby's `select` method?

Comment: Because SQL is built to do queries like that quickly. Ruby's `Array#select` is going to iterate over the entire array and check the condition for each element, making it a relatively slow O(n) operation. That is, `#select` will take 10 times as long on an array with 20 elements as it does on an array with 2 elements. For small arrays you won't notice a significant difference, but if your database grows large doing in sql will be much faster.

Comment: Just for purposes of illustration: running `(0..10000).to_a.select { |i| i < 4 }` 10,000 times takes about 10 seconds on my macbook air, while running `(0..1000).to_a.select { |i| i < 4 }` 10,000 times only takes about 1 second. The difference is that the first array has 10001 elements and the second one only has 1001.

Comment: Or for a more realistic example, I have an `items` table in an actual database that I work with that has 300000 rows. If `category` is a `Category` object that has 656 items, `category.items.where(:name => "foo")` takes less than 5ms, whereas `category.items.select{|i| i.name == "foo"}` takes closer to 7ms.

Comment: And finally, I should say there are exceptions to the general rule of thumb. If, for example, you've already retrieved `f.agreements`, and the collection is small, it might be faster to do an `Array#select` in ruby than doing another database query for a subset of `f.agreements.` Probably for your purposes you won't notice a difference, honestly.